# Unwind embedded document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like below.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "526fdc1fd6b0a8182300009c"
           },
    "body": "test abc",
    "emb" : [{"body":"text","em":"abc.com","auth":"XYZ"},
             {"body":"text","em":"abc.com","auth":"ABC"}
            ]
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "526fdc1fd6b0a8182300009d"
           },
    "body": "test abc",
    "emb" : [{"body":"text","em":"abc.com","auth":"PQR"},
             {"body":"text","em":"abc.com","auth":"ABC"}
            ]
}
```

If I want to count occurrences of each "auth" in the inner array of documents, how can I do that? The result I am expecting is

```
"ABC":2
"PQR":1
"XYZ":1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$unwind` the `emb` array with `{$unwind: "$emb"}`
2. group by `emb.auth` while counting with `{$group: { _id: "$emb.auth", count: { $sum:1 } } }`

This gives you the information you want, although in a slightly different syntax:

```
{ _id:"ABC", count:2 },
{ _id:"PQR", count:1 },
{ _id:"XYZ", count:1 }
```